# Sort ObservableCollection according to its property

Tags: wpf, sorting, observablecollection

I know this has been asked before, but still can't wrap my head around any solution that will work for my case.  I want to be able to sort the observable collection in this project according to the ItemName. here is the full project https://gist.github.com/NewCoderNotInTown/322274bd7d2fd57bf2ae7784e1315b73.

the aim is to have both lists, the original one and the copied one, sorted alphabetically.

appreciate a solution for this case. as simple as possible for a beginner.

I Edit the question with complete code as advised.

Code for MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TwoWindows.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:WB="clr-namespace:TwoWindows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me" Width="80" Height="25"  Click="ClickMe_Click"/>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="WindowB"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <WB:WindowB x:Name="_windowB"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Code for MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TwoWindows
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var windowBViewModel = new WindowBViewModel("WindowB");
        var windowB = new WindowB();

        var windowAViewModel = new WindowAViewModel("WindowA", windowBViewModel);
        var windowA = new WindowA();

        windowA.DataContext = windowAViewModel;
        windowA.Show();

        _windowB.DataContext = windowBViewModel;
    }
   }
  }
```

Code for WindowA.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TwoWindows.WindowA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwoWindows"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowA" Height="300" Width="600">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding PageTitle}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding ItemName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code for WindowA.xaml.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace TwoWindows
  {
  public partial class WindowA : Window
  {
    public WindowA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   }
}
```

Code for WindowB.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TwoWindows.WindowB"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwoWindows"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding PageTitle}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code for WindowB.xaml.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace TwoWindows
{
public partial class WindowB : UserControl
{
    public WindowB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   }
 }
```

Code for WindowAViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TwoWindows
{
public class WindowAViewModel : BaseWindowViewModel
{

    public WindowAViewModel(string pageTitle, WindowBViewModel windowBViewModel)
    {
        PageTitle = pageTitle;

        MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Apple", windowBViewModel));
        MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Orange", windowBViewModel));
        MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Banana", windowBViewModel));
    }
  }
}
```

Code for WindowBViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TwoWindows
{
public class WindowBViewModel : BaseWindowViewModel
{
    public WindowBViewModel(string pageTitle)
    {
        PageTitle = pageTitle;
    }
   }
}
```

Code for MyCustomItemViewModel.cs

```
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TwoWindows
{
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyCustomItemViewModel
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public WindowBViewModel WindowBViewModelObj { get; set; }

    public MyCustomItemViewModel(string itemName, WindowBViewModel windowBViewModel)
    {
        ItemName = itemName;
        WindowBViewModelObj = windowBViewModel;
    }

    private void OnIsCheckedChanged()
    {
        if (IsChecked)
            WindowBViewModelObj.MyItems.Add(this);
        else
            WindowBViewModelObj.MyItems.Remove(this);
      }
   }
}
```

Code for BaseWindowViewModel.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TwoWindows
{
public class BaseWindowViewModel
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> MyItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel>();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's three common ways for sorting from your code.

1. Manually apply the Sort anytime you add items. I would suggest linq for the actual sorting, although you can build your own. In your specific case, it would look like this :

   ```
   MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Apple", windowBViewModel));
   MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Orange", windowBViewModel));
   MyItems.Add(new MyCustomItemViewModel("Banana", windowBViewModel));

   MyItems = MyItems.Sort(p => p.ItemName);
   ```

   This assumes you enable the setter so `MyItems` is not readonly.
2. In the getter for `MyItems`, return the collection sorted (and use a backing property for it). This is not really ideal, since you build the sorted collection for each call that is made to the getter. For your code, it would look like this :

   ```
   public class BaseWindowViewModel
   {
      public string PageTitle { get; set; }

      private ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel>()
      public ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> MyItems 
      {
         get { return _myItems.Sort(p => p.ItemName); }
      }
    }
   ```
3. (Recommended) Work with a CollectionViewSource that sits on top of your collection and applies UI-friendly operations like sorting and filtering.

   ```
   public class BaseWindowViewModel
   {
      public string PageTitle { get; set; }

      private ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> _myItems;
      public ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> MyItems 
      {
         get 
         {
              if (_myItems == null)
              {
                  _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel>();
                  _myItemsSorted = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_myItems)
                  _myItemsSorted.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription() { PropertyName = "ItemName" });
              }
              return _myItems; 
          }
      }

   private ICollectionView _myItemsSorted;
   public ICollectionView MyItemsSorted { get { return _myItemsSorted; }}
   ```

   }

   And then just bind to `MyItemsSorted` rather than `MyItems`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using LINQ, but you'll have to call Sort() when you're done adding or removing items. If that happens a lot with large lists, you may want to look into ObservableCollection.Insert and using your own comparer.

```
public class BaseWindowViewModel
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> MyItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyItems;
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel> _MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel>();

    public void Sort()
    {
        _MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomItemViewModel>(from i in _MyItems orderby i.ItemName select i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0200 Property or indexer 'BaseWindowViewModel.MyItems' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only TwoWindows TwoWindows\WindowAViewModel.cs 31 Active

Comment: You'll have to change MyItems { get; } to MyItems { get; set; }. If you don't want MyItems to be assignable, then you'll need to make MyItems a property that references a private member and change SortMyItems to reference that instead.

Comment: Doesn't sort either lists, am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you call Sort() after adding your items to the collection?

Comment: Hi Tim, Many thanks for your answer, I'm sure it will work as well. I used the other answer above. I just saw your statement about calling Sort, sorry my bad